# How do I solve the following problem with C# and Silverlight? (Shapes on a Canvas)

Tags: c#, silverlight, canvas, shapes

My problem is as follows. I have a Canvas and I have a class called "Node". I create a collection of Nodes, and for each Node I need to some shape (Ellipse, Triangle, Letter) on the canvas at some specific location.

When I click on a Node, I need to be able to go back to the parent Node object and change it.

Adding an MouseLeftButtonUp listener and then going to e.OriginalSource does not work because the original source is of type Ellipse (or some other Shape), not of type Node.

I see two solutions to this problem:

1) If there is some way to attach data to the Ellipse, such as a Node ID, that would be good (something like Ellipse.AddLogicalChild or Ellipse.SetCurrentValue, but I am not sure that would work or if it would be appropriate to use one of those methods).
2) Or, I need the Node to derive some Shape class so that I can add it to Canvas.Children directly.

How do I do either one of these? Or, if you see another solution, please let me know.

Thanks,

Anton Kanevsky

Comment: You can use Dictionary<Shape,Node> for mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your node class could just be a usercontrol that hosts the desired shape as its content. ie: Create the desired shape in the constructor and set as the content, then add the node to the grid.

Alternatively, you can just have the shape be a member of the node class(or not), and subscribe to the events with a node class function. ie: each shape would fire an event in its associated node class.

Comment: could you please elaborate more on your solution?

Comment: Which one? The first is straightforward, just create a blank usercontrol called node, add your custom node code, then in the constructor take an enum or something to determine the shape type, then based on the enum value create a new shape in the constructor and set it as this.Content = newShape name;

Comment: For the second, create a function in the node class that you want to handle the shape click event, for each set of shape-node associations, subscribe the node's function to it's partner shape's event. This would create a one to one mapping. When the node function fires, you can handle the code there, or call a more general purpose function in a higher class passing 'this' (the node reference) along with the shape reference, where both could be handled together.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Dictionary container to sore reference to all of your shapes and nodes. To get the Node given a Shape, just use

```
dict.TryGetValue(shape, out Node);
```